# swift variadic nested function

Tags: swift, function, nested, variadic

Im having trouble in swift using nested functions and variadic inputs. the following function returns an error saying it can not convert type [int] to to expected int the mathFunction has the same input type as defined and given. Do I need to do any sort of converion?

```
func printResults(_ mathFunction: (Int...) -> Double, _ a: Int...)       {
print("Results \(mathFunction(a))")
}
```

Comment: You should probably post the actual error, not your interpretation of it

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `a` is an `[Int]`. `[Int]` cannot (yet) be passed into a closure (`mathFunction`) expecting `Int...`.

There's a ticket open for this, which you can see here: [[SR-128]
Pass array to variadic function](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-128)